# Average value for each row

Tags: c#

I have these classes:

```
public class DelayReason
{
    public virtual ICollection<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }

}
public class WorkOrder 
{
    public virtual ICollection<DelayReason> DelayReasons { get; set; }
 //other fields
}
```

Each `DelayReason` has `0..*` `WorkOrders` and it's the same for `WorkOrders`.

This is a data sample:

[image]

To do this, I've written this code. Can I optimize that?

```
  public void DelayReasonAverage()
    {
        List<ReportVM> result = new List<ReportVM>();

        var reasons = _delayReasons.GroupBy(row => row, (k, t) => new
        {
            delayId = k.Id,
            delayTitle = k.Title,
            workOrders = k.WorkOrders,
            count = t.Count()
        }).OrderByDescending(row => row.count).ToList();

        reasons.ForEach(row =>
        {
            var workOrders = row.workOrders.ToList();

            ReportVM reportObj = new ReportVM() { DelayTitle= row.delayTitle };

            for (int i = 0; i < workOrders.Count; i++)
            {
                if (workOrders.Count - 1 > i)
                    reportObj.Count += workOrders[i].CreatedOn.DiffDays(workOrders[i + 1].CreatedOn);
            }
            reportObj.Count = reportObj.Count / row.count;
            result.Add(reportObj);
        });
    }
```

`DiffDays` extension Method:

```
 public static int DiffDays(this DateTime current,DateTime to)
 {
    return to.Subtract(current).Days;
 }
```

The final results look like this:

[image]

Comment: _below sample is my goal_ you mean this is the result, right? If this is your goal then the question is off-topic because your code is not doing this yet.

Comment: @t3chb0t is it wrong ? where ?

Comment: @t3chb0t Updated , please see new update

Comment: Now it looks good ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t is there any weak code ?

Comment: I think you might have a bug in your `for` loop. Since `i < workOrders.Count` then this `if (workOrders.Count - 1 > i)` is never `true` and the `reportObj.Count` is never increased.

Comment: @t3chb0t - Seems to me that if `i < workOrders.Count` then `(i < workOrders.Count -1)` could also be true, which is the same as `(workOrders.Count - 1 > i)`.  Basically `reportObj.Count` will increase until `i` is 1 less than `workOrders.Count - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

While the logic of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < workOrders.Count; i++)
{
    if (workOrders.Count - 1 > i)
        reportObj.Count += workOrders[i].CreatedOn.DiffDays(workOrders[i + 1].CreatedOn);
}
reportObj.Count = reportObj.Count / row.count;
```

is valid.  I think the for loop might not be necessary.  You should be able to take the difference from the first to last:

```
reportObj.Count = workOrders[0].CreatedOn.DiffDays(workOrders[workOrders.Count - 1].CreatedOn) / row.count;
```

In looking at the rest of that method it looks like the LINQ queries can be simplified quite a bit.  Something like this should work:

```
public List<ReportVM> DelayReasonAverage()
{
    return (from DelayReason dr in _delayReasons
            let row = new
            {
                delayId = dr.Id,
                delayTitle = dr.Title,
                workOrders = dr.WorkOrders.ToList(),
                count = _delayReasons.Count()
            }
            orderby row.count descending
            let reportObj = new ReportVM()
            {
                DelayTitle = row.delayTitle,
                Count = (int)Math.Round(row.workOrders[0].CreatedOn.DiffDays
                (row.workOrders[row.workOrders.Count - 1].CreatedOn) / (double)row.count)
            }
            select reportObj).ToList();
}
```

I noticed your post has this method as void, but it's creating a list, so I changed the signature to reflect that.  I also changed the way the average is calculated, by using Math.Round to get a more accurate reflection of the actual average.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `GroupBy`? I don't see a reason for that. So I would do it that way:

```
public IList<ReportVM> DelayReasonAverage(IList<DelayReason> delayReasons)
{
    // Create the List with the appropriate capacity
    IList<ReportVM> reportVMs = new List<ReportVM>(delayReasons.Count);

    foreach (DelayReason delayReason in delayReasons.OrderByDescending(dr => dr.WorkOrders.Count))
    {
        int delaySumInDays = 0;

        // This .ToList() could be prevented when delayReason.WorkOrders could be IList<WorkOrder>
        var wo = delayReason.WorkOrders.ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < wo.Count - 1; ++i)
        {
            // Why need the DiffDays-Method? For me this is very readable
            delaySumInDays += (wo[i + 1].CreatedOn - wo[i].CreatedOn).Days;
        }

        reportVMs.Add(new ReportVM
        {
            Title = delayReason.Title,
            AverageDays = delaySumInDays / wo.Count
        });
    }

    return reportVMs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
        for (int i = 0; i < workOrders.Count; i++)
        {
            if (workOrders.Count - 1 > i)
                reportObj.Count += workOrders[i].CreatedOn.DiffDays(workOrders[i + 1].CreatedOn);
        }
```

Could be

```
        for (int i = 0; i < workOrders.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            reportObj.Count += workOrders[i].CreatedOn.DiffDays(workOrders[i + 1].CreatedOn);
        }
```